# NTwain: Handling Twain driver Errors doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, scanning

I'm stuck with quite a nasty problem. I have an .net application to scan images with TWAIN driver (using new twaindsm.dll). I'm using the library NTwain for the communication with the scanner and the data/error handling should work like this (see code below):

1. Handling events of TwainSession
2. Init Twainsession and Enable DataSource

```
scanTwain(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{

  var session = new TwainSession(TWIdentity.CreateFromAssembly(DataGroups.Image | DataGroups.Control, Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()));
  
  Exception error = null;
  bool cancel = false;
  DataSource ds = null;
  var waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
  
  
  session.TransferReady += (sender, eventArgs) =>
  {
      //handle transfer ready 
  };
  session.DataTransferred += (sender, eventArgs) =>
  {
      //handle data transfer
  };
  session.TransferError += (sender, eventArgs) =>
  {
      //handle error
      cancel = true;
      StopTwain();
  };
  
  session.SourceDisabled += (sender, eventArgs) =>
  {
      StopTwain();
  };
  
  void StopTwain()
  {
      waitHandle.Set();
  }

  void InitTwain()
  {
      try
      {
          ReturnCode rc = session.Open();
          if (rc != ReturnCode.Success)
          {
              StopTwain();
          }
          ds = session.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == scanDevice.ID);
          rc = ds.Open();
          if (rc != ReturnCode.Success)
          {
              StopTwain();
          }
          //configure DS triplets for specific scanning options..
  
          var ui = SourceEnableMode.NoUI;
          rc = ds.Enable(ui, true, IntPtr.Zero)
          if (rc != ReturnCode.Success)
          {
              StopTwain();
          }
          else
          {
              cancelToken.Register(() =>
              {
                  cancel = true;
                  session.ForceStepDown(5);
              });
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          error = ex;
          StopTwain();
      }
  }

  Invoker.Current.Invoke(InitTwain);
  waitHandle.WaitOne();
  
  if (ds != null && session.IsSourceOpen)
  {
    ds.Close();
  }
  if (session.IsDsmOpen)
  {
    session.Close();
  }
  
  if (error != null)
  {
    throw error;   
  } 
}
```

Scanning images with twain works without problems. The real issue comes with the error handling. If an error on the scanning device occurs like e.g. a paperjam, no DataTransfer error event is triggered and the application is stuck in a loop because there is no message back from the scanning device.

The application itself is built with target Framework .NET 4.7.2 (with preference of 32 bit) and I'm currently using NTwain with version 3.7.1. I also tried different target frameworks and different NTwain versions (down to 3.3.9.5) in many possible combinations but that didn't work either..

As for the twaindsm.dll I'm using the provided one by Fujitsu PaperStream 3.10.

Does somebody have any ideas why the error handling just doesn't want to work?

Regards

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am running into a similar problem

Comment: Unfortunately not. After analyzing it further it seems that there is something wrong with the twain driver itself :/ so i have to guess that it has to do something with a version mismatch of the driver specification